# Sleeping and talking and it's effect on vocal chords

Tags: physical-health

I lie down flat on the floor with a pillow under my head, to narrate long scripts for e-learning. Will this position have an adverse effect on my vocal chords if I keep doing it for the long term?

I find that when I'm lying flat on the floor, I can speak longer sentences in a single breath in comparison to standing /sitting and talking.

Comment: Humans aren't quite so fragile as that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. [Voice Disorders](https://www.asha.org/PRPSpecificTopic.aspx?folderid=8589942600&section=Causes) are caused by many factors include *vocal fatigue* which can result from overuse or increases in [vocal effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_effort). Vocal effort is a messy thing to define, but it generally depends on subglottal pressure and vocal fold tension (as well as other factors). A change in posture can affect vocal effort and it is possible that it could lead to the onset of vocal fatigue faster.

Comment: I don't see anything in your links that supports your assertion. In any case, vocal fatigue doesn't qualify as long-term harm, which is what the question asks.